# How to use ForMember in automapper 4.2 with MapperConfiguration?

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-4

I followed [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API#preserving-static-feel) to preserve the static feel of earlier automapper API but now i am not able to understand how should I use ForMember api, to map specific members. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ForMember` method stills the same:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var destination = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(new Source());
```